# Lightning vs healing vs rage spell for all dragon attack

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm at T.H. 7. In war I use an all dragon attack. I usually don't get 100% when attacking T.H. 8 and was wondering what I can do to change that? In particular I was wondering about the spell use. I often drop 3 lightening spells on an air defense but sometimes maybe something can be done better? For example in the picture bellow would it be a good idea to use range when the dragons get close to all the air defense since they're close together, and rage works best to get through small tough areas?
[image: screen shot of example base]

Comment: Unless the base is poorly designed, its nigh impossible for a TH7 to 3 star a TH8 with dragons

Comment: @BenCraig care to elaborate

Comment: Between army count and troop levels, its very challenging (to near impossible) to 3 star a TH8 while only being a TH7, unless the TH8 is either rushed, or poorly designed

Comment: Or the air defenses are level one and being upgraded at the same time

Comment: You might be able to smash the 2 close air defenses with lightning spells if you drop them at the correct position. There'll be one AD left and if you can get some maxed out CC balloons sent on the lower left cannon (sent after your dragons), they should be able to take out the last AD pretty quickly.

Comment: As Ben said, this is hard to do for a TH7. If the TH8 is not maxed, it might be done, but a maxed well designed TH8 is even a challenge for a TH8 dragon attack using 2 light spells and earthquake to take out an AD and then rage speell for boosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With air defenses that close to each other, it is best to storm in <del>guns firing</del> with dragons with rage spells. ***With the clan castle*** there, two rage spells can be placed for the dragons to quickly take out the air defenses and clan castle troops when attacking from the south of the base. Even with the air sweeper there, the speed boost could help with the recovery and help the dragons attack faster.

Of course, you could face some losses due to the combo of three air defenses... But rage spell should work best if the dragons start going towards center, where the air defenses are. Lightening spells are usually used against TH7 as they only have one air defense left and healing spells are usually used against inferior players/ a raid with lots of low health troops like BARCH.

Comment: Correction: With air defences that close together, it is possible to take out both with 3 lightening spells if you place them exactly in the corner in between. Then the attack should concentrate on targeting the last one, and the rest is a brease...

Answer (score 0):

Two of the air defences are together so you would have to use three lightning spells to take them both out. Then come from the top of the base using dragons. Do be wary of clan castle troops and I would take some archers. Due to the fact there is only one air defence it would be difficult to stop 8 or 9 dragons. Home this helps but you are lucky because two of the air defences are close together.

Answer (score 0):

Use all your lights on the air defences and then swarm with balloons/dragons/minions/lava hounds and bring a rage if you need to - I'm th7 but if you are higher level, I recommend lava hounds.

Answer (score 0):

The base in the example is highly unlikely to be 3 starred in an all dragon attack by a th 7. It is certainly doable but not a gimme for attack by a th 8.
I prefer to use lightnings as my drag attack spells to kill an ad (or 2 ads eventually). There are times though if the ads are close enough to the edges that rages can work well. I do not like healing spells for dragons.

Answer (score 0):

**More general advice for all dragon attacks:**

Two leveled lightnings and a Quake can takeout an anti-air building. If you bring a Quake in the CC spell slot, you can take out 2 anti-air in the base with all 4 of your spells being lightning.

With clever use of your, queen, king and hogs in the CC donation, you can likely take out a third anti-air, leaving only one to pester your dragons.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't apply to Town Hall 7 players, which is what the question is asking about. The Clan Castle doesn't get access to spell storage until TH8, and the Dark Spell Factory isn't available until TH8 as well.

Answer (score -2):

Me and my clan have been debating this for a week rage or lighting we seem to have are own attacks I think it really depends on the base and the player